# How to change currentIndex in BottomNavigationBar from button in another page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page called **FirstScreen.dart**

```
SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            key: _scaffoldKey,
            body: PageView(
              controller: _pageController,
              children: [
                HomeScreen(controller: _pageController),
                PrenotationScreen(),
                AccountScreen(),
                NotificationScreen()
              ],
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              onTap: _onItemTapped,
              currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
              elevation: 0,
              selectedItemColor: kBlackColor,
              backgroundColor: kGoldColor,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              iconSize: 26,
              items: [...]
```

[image]

Inside the **HomeScreen**, I have a button with this function:

```
onPressed: () {
    controller.jumpToPage(1);
},
```

When I click, the function is performed correctly, but does not color the tab.

Change the page but does not color the new current tab

[image]

Comment: Does the color change if you Hot Reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a `onPageChanged` callback to your `PageView`.
Like this:

```
PageView(
  ...
  onPageChanged: (int index)=>setState(()=>_selectedIndex = index),
  ...
),
```